# Are kernels from Ubuntu Kernel PPA supported for the same time frame as the version they are intended for?

Tags: kernel

I wonder if I install a kernel from the Ubuntu Kernel PPA and have 10.04 LTS as my version, because I like the long support period, will they follow the same end of support time?

10.04 LTS desktop has april 2013 and server has april 2015 as end of support. If I look at the Ubuntu Kernel PPA site I cannot find any references to how long they will commit to provide updates. Can I have any expectations at all since it is a PPA?

The kernel packages in 10.04 are supported to april 2015 according to Synaptic.

I don't want to end up with a system that has updates available for everything but the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interested in stability assurance & tech support from Canonical, then a PPA kernel will definitely void that. In https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds they write:

> "The mainline kernels builds are
>   produced for debugging purposes and
>   therefore come with no support. Use
>   them at your own risk."

If you're talking about them continuing with updates, I'd guess they would try - the current LTS is going to have plenty of users, and they don't have to test that much since it's not officially supported. However, some future kernel could include changes that would make it incompatible with 10.04 and they may not bother fixing that.

Comment: This somewhat confirms what I thought would be the case. I would be most concerned about updates in the first place... Thank you!